# cannot export .glb with material setting like specular

Tags: materials, export, gltf

When I export the scene as glTF 2.0 file format, it exports it with textures, but without any material information like specular-ness. I literally set it to 0 in principled BSDF, but when it's exported as glTF 2.0 .glb file it exports without that material setting.

[image]

Above is my node settings in shading tab.

[image]

And this is the result, which shows it exported without material information.

Thanks in advance.

**Solved, Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glTF 2.0's core [material system](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#materials) uses the metallic + roughness PBR system.  You are correct that the specular channel is not currently included.  This may change in a future version of Blender, as there is a newer glTF extension [proposal](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/1719/) for including it inside of the metal/rough workflow.  But it could be some time before that appears in Blender's importer/exporter for glTF.

In the meantime, for this model you may be able to work around this by setting **Roughness** to 1.0.  That should make the material diffuse enough to not show any specular reflection.